# Historical astronomical lunar tables

Tags: the-moon

I hope this is the right place to ask this question, and I apologise if not.

I've come across a date written in an old book, but it is written using what seems to be a lunar/zodiac system.
Below is a picture of the date (ignore the text above it):

[image]

I'm trying to work out what this date would have been in our modern calendar, but I can't seem to find any tables or almanacs that go back that far.

Are there any publicly available tables that do go back to 1587? If not, how exactly could I go about calculating the answer for myself? I am a mathematician, so a bit of wacky maths should be within my capabilities.
This is the answer I'm probably expecting from this site: some kind of program/algorithm/formula to be able to work out on what date the moon would have been in Taurus in

If not, any ideas as to where best for me to ask/look next?

Comment: Would be helpful to know the name of the book. Is it https://books.google.com/books?id=PXoxquU_jgUC ?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate this using the program "KAIROS", See here: http://www.raymondm.co.uk/
It will let you play through the variables: Is this a Julian or a Gregorian date? Is it using true or mean positions? And so forth.

Answer (score 2):

You probably got this far yourself, but here is my absolutely wild 
speculative guess on why this could be 24 May 1587 on the Gregorian 
calendar:

- It seems fairly clear that this refers to the 24th of some month 
  in 1587, but it's not as clear which month this is, and whether this 
  is in the Gregorian or Julian calendar.
- The moon symbol followed by the symbol for Taurus may indicate 
  "the month where the new moon was in Taurus". This is slightly 
  ambigious, since the new moon is was Taurus on both June 6th and May 
  7th, but I believe May 7th slightly is more likely for the reasons 
  below.
- Wikipedia notes that "cerasus" is a a dated synonym of the genus 
  Prunus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerasus), which includes 
  cherries.
- Historically, there is no "Cherry Moon" (although there are songs, 
  movies, and possibly more that mention it), but cherry trees are 
  known for their flowers, so this may be a reference to the Full 
  Flower Moon of May:

http://farmersalmanac.com/full-moon-names/

- The word "gexia" translates to "Your Mightiness" in Chinese:

https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/gexia

but I'm pretty sure this is red herring, since the paper doesn't 
appear to be in Chinese, and I'm not sure Chinese transliteration even 
existed at the time. However, it would fit in nicely.

- So this could be saying "the full cherry (flower) moon occurs on 
  24 May 1587". Unfortunately, the actual full moon occurs late on the 
  22nd GMT, so the 24th is a bit of a stretch even allowing for the 
  16th century equivalent of "time zones"
- The Gregorian calendar reform occurred in 1582. Many countries 
  didn't adopt it until much later, but the text appears to be in a 
  Latin-based language (ie, a Romance language), and countries like 
  this were quick to switch to the Gregorian calendar:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar#Adoption_in_Catholic_countries

- If this is 24 May 1587 in the Julian calendar, it would be 10 days 
  later, 3 Jun 1587, in the Gregorian calendar. This date seems less 
  likely, since there is no full moon on that date, though there is 
  almost a new moon in Taurus, so maybe.

So why would the author write "month of moon in Taurus" instead of the 
actual month name? It's possible he was trying to be careful, since 
the months would be different in the many countries still using the 
Julian calendar.

Of course, it may just be a reference to the lunar eclipse of 24 Mar 1587:

http://eclipsewise.com/lunar/LEprime/1501-1600/LE1587Mar24Tprime.html

Comment: Romanians call June *ciresar* (*cireasa* means cherry). *Taurus* is commonly associated with late April to late May.